# Android: Resource Qualifiers on src folder

Tags: android, lottie, android-resource-qualifiers

Is it possible to separate out my src folder by resource qualifier? I already have my code (src, res, etc) separated by product flavor, but I want to separate my src folder in one of the flavors further by portrait and landscape.

- android project

  - flavor1

    - src
    - res
  - flavor2

    - src-port
    - src-land

Is something like this possible? I'm using some software that converts After Effects to YML (similar to [Lottie](https://airbnb.design/lottie/)) (AE->YML->Java) but the Java source file that is generated as a result is essentially locked to whatever dimension the AE file is, ie:

```
/*
        Scene information
    */
    public static final String SOURCE_NAME = "DetailsView";

    public static final int WIDTH = 1920;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 50;

    public static final float FRAMERATE = 30f;
```

this works great in default/landscape orientation, but in portrait I would need to generate another AE project with a `WIDTH` of `1080`, which would create another variant of this source file that cannot coexist with the first. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: Actually stuff like width or height of something should be determined dynamically. That would solve your problem immediately as there would be no need for code duplication. Is there a reason why that isn't suitable?

Answer (score 0):

> Is something like this possible?

No, sorry.